# Can't add values from req.body to mongoose Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to upload a small image with extra fields like "price". The img seems to be stored in the destined folder but the extra fields are not saved with the file.

I'm using multer and bodyParser.json to be able to read the fields of req.body and req.file.

here's the post:

```
router.route('/pictures/add').post(upload, (req, res) => {


        console.log(req.body.price); //works
        console.log(req.file); //works

    var picture = new Picture({
        name : req.file.originalname,
        price : req.body.price,
        id : req.file.filename
    }); 


    console.log(picture); //logs only the id as in req.file.filename. 
    //name and price are missing

    picture
        .save()
        .then(picture => {
            console.log(picture);
            res.status(201).json({
                picture: 'Added successfully',
                id: picture.id, //id as in req.file.filename
                name: picture.name, //missing
                price: picture.price //missing
            });
        })
```

Here's the multer instance

```
const upload = multer({dest: 'pictures/'}).single('img');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Here's the Picture Schema

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Picture = new Schema({
    name: {
        Type: String
    },
    price: {
        Type: String
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Picture', Picture);
```

I expected the DB to save all the fields like so: id, name, price
but only id seems to be send and saved to the DB.

I welcome any help.

Comment: show req.body.price and req.file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is easy: when defining a schema type the keyword "type" has to be lowercase, not uppercase. The Server threw an exception after i set an default value for the field "name".